# C: printf. the outputs are fluctuating i.e they don't follow a pattern

Tags: c

if i do `printf("%")` there is no output.

If i do `printf("%%%")` the output is same as `printf("%%")` i.e `%`.

Now the output for `printf("%%%%%%")` is `%%%`. Why this is happening

Comment: You should **read the documentation** of [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) *before asking* here!

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I looked over the doc you referenced.  Even though I am well acquainted with `printf()`, I did not find anything there that addresses a lone `"%"`.  Of course the C spec does address it.

Answer (score 4):

Because `%` is for a 'placholder' (format specifiers) like `%d` or `%s` in `printf()`

So to actually print `%` you have to write `%%`

So:

```
%     -> ''
%%    -> '%'
%%%   -> '%'
%%%%  -> '%%'
%%%%% -> '%%'
```

(BTW: If you print an odd number of `%` like: `printf("%")` it could be that you get this error: `[Warning] spurious trailing '%' in format [-Wformat]`)

Answer (score 1):

With `printf()`

> "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined" C11dr §7.21.6.1 9

`"%"` begins a conversion specifier like `"%*d"`, `"%5f"`, `"%%"` (print a single `'%'`).  Without a proper ending, a lone `"%"` is invalid, therefore anything may happen.

Answer (score 0):

With just `%` no arguement is converted and you see nothing.

In order to just print `%` you have to use `%` specifier before that.

```
printf("%%");
```

The same applies for any number of `%` being printed.

Check this link: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html